# Selecting html class inside modal with JS to show name of file in upload form (in Laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I have the following modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Upload de Anexo</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="{{ route('ordem_attachment.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="hidden" id="ordem_id" name="ordem_id" value="{{ $ordem->id }}">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="attachment_id">Tipo de Anexo</label>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <select class="form-control" name="attachment_id">
              <option disabled selected value> -- Selecione um Tipo de Anexo -- </option>
              @forelse($attachments as $att)
              <option value="{{ $att->id }}">{{ $att->descricao }}</option>
              @empty
              @endforelse
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" name="anexo" id="file" class="custom-file-input">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="file">Selecionar Arquivo</label>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the following JS code to try to show the name of the file when one is selected:

```
<script>
    document.querySelector('.custom-file-input').addEventListener('change',function(e){
      var fileName = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
      var nextSibling = e.target.nextElementSibling
      nextSibling.innerText = fileName
    })
</script>
```

But it is not working and I couldn't figure out why. The file is uploaded normally but i can't show the name of the selected file in the form.

Comment: Could you try to `console.log(document.getElementById("file").files[0].name)` and tell us the output? (After you have selected a file to upload).

Comment: I think maybe that is my problem, none of the console.log messages are showing in the console, is the selector being done correctly?

Comment: Ah yes, the selector is done correctly but since you are only selecting one file it is not going to be an array only one single file, try to erase the array indexing.

Comment: Still doesn't print, not even the plain text messages I'm trying are not printing

Comment: working on this right now: <script>
    console.log("before change");
    document.querySelector('.custom-file-input').addEventListener('change',function(e){
      console.log("after change");
    })
    </script>, it only prints the first message

Comment: Just so I understand, you want to display the filename on the label for file, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219975/discussion-between-trukken-and-erick-skrobot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
var fileName = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
```

you can try with

```
let file=e.target.files[0];

var fileName = file['name'];
```

if not working you can try also using onchange event like this
in your HTML add onchange="fileFunction()"

```
<div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" name="anexo" id="file" class="custom-file-input" onchange="fileFunction()">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="file">Selecionar Arquivo</label>
    </div>
```

and in your javascript add

```
function fileFunction(e){
             
                alert(document.getElementById("file").files[0].name);
                }
```

after uploading the file  the alert will show the file name

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i don't think the javascript is detecting the change, is the selector being done correctly? Because the console.log tests I'm trying are not being printed in the console.

Comment: I was able to get it to work! Your onchange event suggestion was what worked for me. Thanks!